# Bootstrap Top Nav Bar: Margins and Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the example **starter-template.css** which is the simplest 1-column page with a header.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knbxy2d8/

I don't understand where the **full black header** is, from top to bottom. If you select the black header in Firebug which is really the first element,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">
```

that only selects 90% of the height of this black bar, but not the whole bar. Where do the top/bottom black sections come from?

My issue is, I need to know the exact height and container of the header because I'm styling it in Photoshop. It will be a background image. So it needs to replace any black sub-bars with one full div. Why does Bootstrap do it like this?

[image]

BTW, regarding this comment:
*it's 54px high in mobile but 56px*
So how would I replace it with a consistent image? Can I force it to be the same height?

Comment: 54 pixels high. Top and bottom black sections come from padding.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing in firebug? Chrome's developer tools shows .5 rem padding top and bottom on the nav element from the topbar class.

Comment: @Gerard it's 54px high in mobile but 56px in desktop, there is no fixed height applied.

Comment: Yes image uploaded in the main post. As you can see, the NavBar selection only selects 90% of the header. However, I'm unable to  select anything else, there is no element there. Firebug doesn't show any padding or margins, there is nothing below in that window.

Comment: When you say "a consistent image", is this a background image for the navbar instead of a solid colour? If so does it tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as I can't post an image in a comment.

As you can see from the screenshot of chrome's developer tools below, the blank space you are seeing is .5rem of padding on the top and bottom of the `nav` element applied by the `.navbar` class.

[image: chrome's developer tools]

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. But how would I apply an image if it's sometimes 54 and 56px?

Comment: What sort of image? It could be that you could get away with setting ``background-size: contain`` which would always make the image match the closest dimension (most likely height here)

Comment: You can also use "max-height" on the image and set it to a percentage like 95% or 100% or whatever suits your fancy.